# Dawn of doomsday

Tags: astronomy, stars, solar-system

If the Sun were part of a binary star system, and the second star was significantly smaller and collided with our own planets:

1. Would the second star explode in the form of a supernova?
2. Could such a supernova cause the Sun to erupt as a chain reaction?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it shows a lack of any research.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, No.

It is unlikely that a planet in a stable orbit would quite suddenly leave its orbit and even less likely that it would crash directly into another body in a stable orbit in the same system. Not *impossible* though, because orbits of smaller planets in a 3 or more body system are mathematically chaotic.

A main sequence star could absorb a planet quite easily. The results would be well short of going nova, but there might be enough of a flare to imperil your planet. As for supernova, this is a sort of implosion-explosion which can only happen to a large star at a particular stage of its evolution. Most commonly a red giant star that runs out of fuel.

A supernova within light-minutes of a habitable planet would be its fiery end, but a star would not suffer more than slight disruption on the stellar scale of things. Actually a supernova a whole lightyear distant might doom all life. One within forty lightyears is likely to cause a mass extinction event. A supernova is a truly cataclysmic event!

Comment: A slight correction: Red giants do not become supernovae. They are a later evolutionary stage of stars like the Sun, and then shed their outer layers and become white dwarfs. Red *supergiants* may be supernova progenitors; the same is true for supergiants of various other spectral types, especially massive O and B stars.

Comment: First I'm not.  Suggesting the planets are leaving their standard orbits but that the orbital paths Intersect. Also I presume that it may be possible the second star being as claimed a brown dwarf if it's mass may be small enough to be affected by one or more of our larger planets.